# How do we know that $(\frac {\partial \mathbf r}{\partial u} \times \frac {\partial \mathbf r}{\partial v}) $ is a unit vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The two formulas I have for surface integrals are $\int_S \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n dS$ and $\int_{\gamma} \mathbf v(\mathbf r(u,v)) \cdot \left(\frac {\partial \mathbf r}{\partial u} \times \frac {\partial \mathbf r}{\partial v}\right) dudv$.  If these are the same thing then doesn't that mean that $\left(\frac {\partial \mathbf r}{\partial u} \times \frac {\partial \mathbf r}{\partial v}\right)$ has to be equal to $\mathbf n$, which is a unit vector?  I don't see how for *any* parametrization we make, that cross product will always be of unit length.

Can someone explain to me what I'm missing here?

Comment: You are correct in that the cross product usually is not a unit vector. But that $dS$ compensates for this because we have
$$dS=||\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial v}||\,du\,dv.$$ Together with ${\bf n}$ we get the claimed formula.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I seem to recall something like $dxdy = J\ dsdt$, where $J$ is the Jacobian.  So is $\| \frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial v}\|$ equal to the Jacobian of the transformation $dxdy \mapsto dudv$?  And if so, how could I prove that?

Comment: More or less. I'm a bit hesitant to call it Jacobian, because $\bf r$ is (presumably) a 3D-vector. Anyway, the idea is that in 3D (as well as 2D) the parallelogram with sides $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ has area $||\vec{a}\times\vec{b}||$. Here we apply this to the infinitesimal vectors $\vec{a}=(\partial r/\partial u)\,du$ and $\vec{b}=(\partial r/\partial b)\,dv$.

Comment: So we start with a unit square with sides $dx$ and $dy$ (where the "units" in this unit square are $dx$ and $dy$).  Then we transform $dx\ \hat x \mapsto (\partial \mathbf r/ \partial u)du$ and $dy\ \hat y \mapsto (\partial \mathbf r/ \partial v)dv$ which maps that unit square to some parallelogram.  The norm of that parallelogram is then $\|(\partial \mathbf r/ \partial u)du \times (\partial \mathbf r/ \partial v)dv\| = \|(\partial \mathbf r/ \partial u)\times (\partial \mathbf r/ \partial v)\|dudv$?  I'm not entirely sure where that mapping comes from but it does seem to make sense.  Thanks.

Comment: That's the idea. I do think you start with a tile with dimensions $du \cdot dv$. Those $u$ and $v$ are coordinates parametrizing the surface $S$. No $x$s and $y$s in that parameter spaces. More like
$$(x,y,z)={\bf r}(u,v),$$ so all of $x,y,z$ are functions of both $u,v$.